# String to UK Date Format

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

I have something resembling the below.

```
mth = 08
dy = 12
yr = 2014
dt = dy & "/" & mth & "/" & yr
Cells(i,j) = dt
```

When the code runs, the date is converted to US format so actually appears as mmddyyyy instead of ddmmyyyy.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run

```
 Cells(i,j).NumberFormat = "dd mm yyyy"
```

and it shoould be ok

Answer (score 0):

Although you already have an answer, I'll throw this one in as well as my preferred method:

```
Cells(i,j) = DateSerial(yr, mth, dy)
```

This should avoid any unexpected formatting because you aren't putting the values into a string and asking VBA to then convert the string to a date.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim mth     As Integer
    Dim dy      As Integer
    Dim yr      As Integer
    Dim dt      As Date

    mth = 8
    dy = 12
    yr = 2014
    dt = Format(DateSerial(yr, mth, dy), "dd mm yyyy")
    Cells(1, 1) = dt

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to do with it. If you are going to use it for display only, u can prepend the value with an apostrophe. This instructs Excel to interpret the value as text.

```
dt = "'" & dy & "/" & mth & "/" & yr
```

If you want to do date calculation (including sorting), you can use the proposed `DateSerial' functions but you have to set the formatting of the column to the desired format as well otherwise Excel will use the default format.

```
Cells(i,j).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```